# Excel: Dropdown based Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a dropdown where the user can select their desired brand.

```
HP
Dell
Razer
Apple
```

In the second dropdown the user selects their desired build (for example i7) and then it returns the price.

```
i5
i7
i9

=VLOOKUP(A1;'Apple'!A1:B3;2;FALSE)
```

How can I make the 'Apple' part of Vlookup above dynamic, based on the original dropdown choice? The sheets are identical excluding the price so the cells are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INDIRECT` formula to build a string

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;INDIRECT("'" & C4 & "'!A1:B3");2;FALSE)
```

if your sheet name is in C4, adjust to suit.

Comment: I was thinking about INDIRECT but I had no idea how to use it. I need to learn this more. Thank you!